# Sails.io.js : Check if Socket connection is established or not

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io, sails.js

I'm trying to use sails.io.js with `nodewebkit`

I'm setting url of my sails server with the line :

```
io.sails.url = "http://localhost:1337";
```

I want to know If socket is successfully connected or not, so that I can alert users if there is any network issue.

I am currently using `timeout` of 1000 milliseconds to check if socket connection is established or not:

```
$timeout(function () {
  if(io.socket.socket.connected)
     socketConnected = true;
  else
     socketConnected = false;
}, 1000);
```

If I dont use timeout, it goes asynchronous and above function is executed first instead of socket connection.

Is there any way I can know if socket connection is established or not without using `timeout`. Any Ideas?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `connect` event to determine when a socket connection is established:

```
io.socket.on('connect', function() {...});
```

But you'll still need a timeout, because you're checking whether a connection is...timing out!

```
var socketTimeout = $timeout(function () {alert('socket timed out!');}, 5000);
io.socket.on('connect', function() {$timeout.cancel(socketTimeout);})
```